Problem with get the current response from Google Forms using Apps Script
I'm having a problem with getting the current response from Google Forms. My objective is get a number from a input from Forms and make a multiplication table of this number. I'm using Apps Script to get the number and returning it to the response page. A tried of a lot of ways, but every time the response show the penultimate number sent and not the current one. For examble: I give the number 7 for the code calculate the multiplication table, but instead it shows the multiplication table of the number 4 that I sent before. And just in the next try it shows the multiplication table of the number 7.
Img1
Img2
This is my code:
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var responses = form.getResponses(); // Get all responses

    // Get the last response
    var lastResponse = responses[responses.length - 1];

    // Get the individual responses from the last response
    var itemResponses = lastResponse.getItemResponses();

    // Now you can manipulate the individual responses as desired
    var num = parseInt(itemResponses[0].getResponse());

    Logger.log(num)

    // Build the confirmation message based on the last response
    var confirmationMessage = "Multiplication table of " + num + ":\n\n";
  
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        confirmationMessage += num + " x " + i + " = " + num * i + "\n";
    }

    // Set the custom confirmation message
    form.setConfirmationMessage(confirmationMessage);

}

And this how is configured my trigger:
Img3

First, if I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize. At that time, please tell me. About A tried of a lot of ways, but every time the response show the penultimate number sent and not the current one., I think that from your showing script and trigger, the current submitted result is shown after the next submission. I think that in this case, the result with the current submitted value cannot be shown just after the current submitted form. I guessed that this might be the reason for it.

You have script executed by a onFormSubmit Installable trigger. The script updates the "Confirmation Message" based on a question answer (expressed as an integer). Your expectation is that it should update the Confirmation Message for the current recipient. However you find that the Confirmation Message for the current recipient is always based on the value entered by the penultimate recipient.
The script is processing correctly and as expected.
The issue is a misunderstanding about execution of the onFormSubmit trigger.

The script is triggered when the user submits the Form. That is, the user's response will not update any content for the current user.
The Confirmation Message is updated after the user submits the Form so the next user to submit the Form will see the updated message.
It is not possible to dynamically update the Confirmation Message for the current user.

